# My clues in my game are off (java)

Tags: java

My brother offered me a challege to help my studies by making a game that only runs in the main method instead of using other classes to make sure I still remember my old stuff. Bases off that I went with a cat and mouse game where the player is the mouse looking for the cheese while avoiding all the cats. When you enter an empty "room" (cell) the game is supposed to give you a clue at how far you are from the cheese. Now the game runs but my clues just keep going higher and higher to the point where it over the amount of rooms in the maze. I am stumpped on where the problem is.

Here's the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class CatAndMouse
{
    public static final int MAX = 10;

    public static void main(String args[ ]) 
    {
        Scanner mouse = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random placement = new Random();

        boolean check = true, gameOver = false, win = false, lose = false;

        final int row = MAX;
        final int col = MAX;
        final int page = MAX;       

        int cheeseX, cheeseY, cheeseZ;
        int cheese = 1;

        int catX, catY, catZ;
        int cat = 2;

        int mouseRow;
        int mouseCol;
        int mousePage;
        int mouseMove;

        int empty = 0;

        int clue = 0;
        int clueCount = 0;

        int winQuotes;
        int loseQuotes;

        int [][][]maze = new int [row][col][page];

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
                {
                    maze[i][j][k] = empty;
                }//page
            }//col
        }//row

        cheeseX = placement.nextInt(row);
        cheeseY = placement.nextInt(col);
        cheeseZ = placement.nextInt(page);


        maze[cheeseX][cheeseY][cheeseZ] = cheese;

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            catX = placement.nextInt(row);
            catY = placement.nextInt(col);
            catZ = placement.nextInt(page);

            maze[catX][catY][catZ] = cat;

            if ((maze[catX][catY][catZ]) == (maze[cheeseX][cheeseY][cheeseZ]))
            {
                catX = placement.nextInt(row);
                catY = placement.nextInt(col);
                catZ = placement.nextInt(page);

                maze[catX][catY][catZ] = cat;
            }//if place with cheese                     
        }//cat placement loop

        System.out.println("Hello there, my name is Q, do you like it? it's short for Q. So you're probably asking yourself \"why am I now a mouse?\"");
        System.out.println("The answer is simple, I was bored and you humans are so much fun to play with, but don't worry I can change you back.");
        System.out.println("All you have to do is win my little game and you'll be back to your old self again, loose and...well just don't lose.");
        System.out.println("In this maze there is a piece of cheese, find it and you win. But be careful now, I added a \'few\' cats to hunt you.");
        System.out.println("Can't make this too easy now can we? But don't worry, you'll be given clues if you're close to the cheese or not");
        System.out.println("The maze itself is 10*10*10 and to move through it enter an integer between 0-9.");
        System.out.println("Now then, let the game begin.");

        System.out.println();

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter row: ");
                mouseRow = mouse.nextInt();

            if((mouseRow < 0) || (mouseRow > 9))
            {
                while (check == true)
                {
                    System.out.print("I said, it needs to be an integer between 0-9. Try again: ");
                        mouseRow = mouse.nextInt();

                    if((mouseRow >= 0) && (mouseRow <= 9))
                        check = false;
                }//while closer
            }//row check

            check = true;

            System.out.print("Enter column: ");
                mouseCol = mouse.nextInt();

            if((mouseCol < 0) || (mouseCol > 9))
            {
                while (check == true)
                {
                    System.out.print("I said, it needs to be an integer between 0-9. Try again: ");
                        mouseCol = mouse.nextInt();

                    if((mouseCol >= 0) && (mouseCol <= 9))
                        check = false;
                }//while closer
            }//column check

            check = true;

            System.out.print("Enter page: ");
                mousePage = mouse.nextInt();

                        if((mousePage < 0) || (mousePage > 9))
            {
                while (check == true)
                {
                    System.out.print("I said, it needs to be an integer between 0-9. Try again: ");
                        mousePage = mouse.nextInt();

                    if((mousePage >= 0) && (mousePage <= 9))
                        check = false;
                }//while closer
            }//page check

            check = true;

            mouseMove = maze[mouseRow][mouseCol][mousePage];

            System.out.println();


            /*================[Win/Lose]===============*/               

            if (mouseMove == 2)
            {
                gameOver = true;
                lose = true;
            }//loser

            if (mouseMove == 1)
            {
                gameOver = true;
                win = true;
            }//winner

            /*===============[Win/Lose]===============*/


            /*=================[Clue]=================*/    

            if(mouseRow == cheeseX)
            {   
                System.out.println("In same row as cheese!");

            }//if same row

            else if (mouseRow > cheeseX)
            {
                for(int i = cheeseX; i <= mouseRow; i++)
                {
                    clueCount++;
                }//for loop closer
            }//if mouse is larger

            else
            {
                for(int i = mouseRow; i <= cheeseX; i++)
                {
                    clueCount++;
                }//for loop closer
            }//else cheese is larger    

            clue = clue + clueCount;

            if(mouseCol == cheeseY)
            {
                System.out.println("In same column as cheese!");

            }//if same colum    

            if (mouseCol > cheeseY)
            {
                for(int i = cheeseY; i <= mouseCol; i++)
                {
                    clueCount++;
                }//for loop closer
            }//if mouse is larger

            else
            {
            for(int i = mouseCol; i <= cheeseY; i++)
                {
                    clueCount++;
                }//for loop closer
            }//else cheese is larger    

            clue = clue + clueCount;

            if(mousePage == cheeseZ)
            {   
                System.out.println("In same page as cheese!");

            }//if same page 

            if (mousePage > cheeseZ)
            {
                for(int i = cheeseZ; i <= mousePage; i++)
                {
                    clueCount++;
                }//for loop closer
            }//if mouse is larger

            else
            {
                for(int i = mousePage; i <= cheeseZ; i++)
                    {
                        clueCount++;
                    }//for loop closer
            }//else cheese is larger    

            clue = clue + clueCount;

            System.out.println("You are " + clue + " cells away from the cheese.");

            System.out.println();
            /*=================[Clue]=================*/


        }while (gameOver == false);

        if (win == true)
        {
            winQuotes = (int)(3 * Math.random()) + 1;

            switch (winQuotes)  
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("You found the cheese! Now it's time to send you back, but don't worry. I'm sure we'll meet again soon.");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("An excellent job, maybe you were meant to be a mouse all long. What, change you back? Oh fine.");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Congradulation, I don't think Captian Picard couldn't have done it better. Maybe I should pay him a visit.");
                    break;
            }//win switch
        }//if you won

        if (lose == true)
        {
            loseQuotes = (int)(3 * Math.random()) + 1;

            switch(loseQuotes)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Well at least you fed a hungry cat right? Star Fleet would be so proud to have you on one of their ships.");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Oh come on, don't tell me you wore a red shirt before I brought you here.");
                    break;

                 default:
                    System.out.println("Maybe I should have brought Captian Janeway here instead, I still owe her for that punch to my face.");
                    break;

             }//lose switch
         }//if you lose
     }//main closer
 } //class closer
```

Comment: "My brother offered me a challege to help my studies by making a game that only runs on the main method instead of other classes to make sure I still remember my old stuff."

And why aren't you allowed to split things up into helper functions within the same class? Having one gigantic function is bad practice.

Comment: Interesting, go to this site: [find my problem.com](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Gawd, sorry, I'd love to help but it's just a ton of code :(

Comment: If anything this sort of monstrosity will hinder your studies

Comment: P.s. I don't mean your program itself which is probably the best you can do with this insane restriction.  I mean the insane restriction

Comment: When a language offers you tools like classes use them. It doesn't make you a better programmer of you cram every line of code inside one method. If you have to comment the closing brackets you know your design is not as good as it could be.

Comment: If you want to do things old school, I'd say the equivalent is only using static methods. Still pointless but no longer insane and pointless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never reinitialize your `clue` variable to 0 in your `do/while` loop. So, everytime you run through the loop, instead of setting `clue` to the current clue value, you keep adding to it (`clue = clue + clueCount`).

Answer (score 5):

You aren't resetting `clue` to zero in the big do-while loop
So it's seems logical to me that the clues can't do anything but go higher, because it keep adding the new count to itself (`clue = clue + clueCount`)